# CSS Footer background image won't show up

Tags: javascript, html, css

The background image of the footer won't show up.
Note: No errors in Chrome developer tools.

CSS Code:

```
.mini1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 6.7%;
  margin-top: -2%;
  background-image: url('../images/footer1.jpg');
  z-index: 10;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<footer class="mini1">
    ....
</footer>
```

EDIT:
   The parent of footer in this case is the  tag.

EDIT:
   For people thinking about the path:
  [image]

EDIT: There is content inside the tag.

Comment: My crystal ball is out for repairs, so I'll need an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: is path to image correct? also, try without `margin-top: -2%;` and see if it appears and why do you have `z-index` without a `position`?

Comment: Height should be given in pixel.

Comment: Is the URL right? Relative URL's are relative to the stylesheet, not the document.

Comment: @Maddy : not if your parent div is also in percentage dimension!

Comment: Your code should work. check the image path. http://jsfiddle.net/knftvt6v/

Comment: @NoobEditor Doesn't help..

Comment: @GeorgeCloone-y : add `background-size : 100% 100%;` and see!

Comment: You need content in your footer for it to work too, not sure if you have it or not. Add `&nbsp;` within your footer and try

Comment: @GeorgeCloone-y : and what is this supposed to mean?

Comment: @NoobEditor That it didn't work.

Comment: do you have any content in your footer? give a fiddle of it...

Comment: Is the footer otherwise rendered correctly? (i.e. without a background image) In that case I would test the img path somewhere else in my css, even though it seems weird. Can you see if the rule is being evaluated or overwritten in Chrome Devtools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
.mini1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 6.7%;
    margin-top: -2%;
    background-image: url('../images/footer1.jpg');
    z-index: 10;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Please see to it that, image path is correct. Go in console to check for any errors.

Comment: Changed to that. No errors in console. No background either, yet the content is showing.

Comment: The background-image is not getting displayed or the contents are not been displayed????
What is getting displayed displayed in your browser??

Answer (score 0):

Well here is a working JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/knftvt6v/4/

I believe it is your file path that's causing the error, can you make a JS fiddle

```
.mini1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2em;
    margin-top: -2%;
    background: url('http://www.serenitybaumer.com/main_images/footer.jpg');
    z-index: 10;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I added this block of code in which worked fine

Comment: background-image: url('http://www.serenitybaumer.com/main_images/footer.jpg');

Changed to that and still no background.

Comment: Did you remove the gaps in your HTML I.e <footer class="mini1">  instead off <footer class = "mini1">?